# Does hashchange event fire when hash is removed?

Tags: javascript, events, hashchange, mithril.js

I used both jquery hashchange and window.addEventListener("hashchange") but the event not firing when hash part is removed by code. I'm using mithril.js to change hash:

```
m.route('')

window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(evt) {
    console.log("hash change");
    var path = location.hash.substring(1);
    console.log(path);
    //do other things
}, false);
```

Does the event fire when hash part of the url removed? If not what is the workaround to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fire if `history.pushState()` is used to remove the hash.

According to [mithril.js docs](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/blob/80f43c260b710a09bdec875b0e596293c3727801/docs/tools.md#internet-explorer-compatibility):

> In addition, note that most `m.route` modes rely on `history.pushState` in order to allow moving from one page to another without a browser refresh.